# intellij messes up with tabs in non-program files

Tags: intellij-idea

so i just spent some time fussing over why my String.split call in scala failed - i was trying to split on a tab.

Problem wasn't what i was doing, but rather the fact that intelliJ changes  tabs to spaces. Fair enough, but can i tell intelliJ to *not* do that for some files - like say random text files I might be using for test/learning purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would turn on `Settings > Editor > Appearance > Show whitespaces`, that way you're SURE what white space characters are there.

Next, under `Settings > Code Style > General` there should be a `Use tab character` check box. This says "use tabs for anything that's not Java, Scala, HTML, etc.". Just make sure `Java`, `Scala`*, etc. `Use tab character` setting is set to what you want.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to be more fine grained with what file types do and do not use tabs vs. spaces.

*I'm assuming the IntelliJ Scala plugin adds a tab in `Settings > Code Style`.